# Reflection on static memebers in ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, reflection

Actually this is more than one question, but seems kind related. I appreciate any lead on any one of them.

1. Is there a way to "reflect on" static members of an ActionScript object (get all the static properties/methods of that type programmatically)?
2. Why is that flash.utils.describeType(*) can only show non-static members?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call describeType and pass the class of the object, rather than the object, you'll get the static properties.

i.e.: static:

```
describeType( Sprite );
```

non-static:

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite;
describeType( s );
```